# Turning standard output hyphen into a single command

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdout

I am working with scripts that output xml and I am using xmllint to format the output. Xmllint requires a source argument, so I use the hyphen to pipe standard output to it:

```
$> script.php source.txt | xmllint --format - > nice_output.xml
```

Since I run these scripts quite a bit, I would like to turn the `xmllint --format -` part into a single command that I can pipe into, but I am not sure how to even start. I would like to do this:

```
$> script.php source.txt | nicexml > nice_output.xml
```

Where `nicexml` is my custom command/alias. How do I do this?

Comment: Doesn't a plain old alias work? (`-` has no shell magic, it's passed as-is to the process as an argument.)

Comment: I tried an alias from H.-Dirk Schmitt's answer but it didn't work; I didn't see what I did wrong.

Comment: Never say just "didn't work". That can't help anyone help you fix anything. Describe the error/misbehavior.

Comment: I got a blank output with no error, with and without preceding dollar sign.

Comment: I guess I didn't restart properly enough, it works now (got expected output) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### alias version

```
alias nicexml="xmllint --format -"
```

#### bash function

```
function nicexml() { xmllint --format "${@:--}"; }
```

- Default input is *stdin*
- Allows also alternative input source and options.

Comment: How do I call it as an alias? I put that line in my .bash_rc, started a new bash session, but it doesn't seem to work, either as `nicexml` or `$nicexml`.

Comment: The alias as : `script.php source.txt | nicexml` , but take care - in the 1st version was a small typo.

Comment: The function is better - it supports `script.php source.txt | nicexml` and `nicexml myFile.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You could define a shell variable `nicexml="xmllint --format -"`
and then use it as `$nicexml`.